# Markings on a capacitor

Tags: capacitor, pcb, pcb-design

I ran across a capacitor that has "200 A1J" with 200 above the A1J. I think 200 means 20pF and J means 5% tolerance, but what does the A1 mean?
[image: Cap in question]

Comment: Please include a good photo of the part in question.

Comment: Quite possibly the working voltage. As Spehro said, put a good photo of the component.

Comment: I added a picture. I know it is blurry but it being so super small it is extremely hard to take a picture of

Answer (score 4):

A is the dielectic (A=C0G) and 1 is the voltage rating (1=100V). The image below is an edited excerpt from the [Kyocera/AVX Skycap series datasheet](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/40/SR_Series-3165337.pdf).
[image]

(Source: [protosupplies.com](https://protosupplies.com/product/capacitor-multilayer-ceramic-10pf-100v-cog-5-pack/))